# Imagen responsiva con css

Tags: css, css3

Tengo una imagen circular la cual deseo hacer responsiva, mi problema es que se mantiene el mismo tamaño. Esto es lo que tengo

```css
.image-cropper {
  width: 215px;
  height: 215px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img_circular {
  background: #eee;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="col s2">
  <a href="#!user">
    <div class="image-cropper">
      <img class="img_circular" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0d/12/d7/3b/img-20160923-wa0089-largejpg.jpg">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

les comparto mi [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dimoreno/20xb4nrr/)

De antemano les agradezco

Comment: Intenta reemplazando width: auto; por width: 100%; en .img-circular

Comment: no amigo no cambia en nada, gracias por tu aporte

Comment: De nada sirve si el contenedor de la imagen tienen un ancho fijo en píxeles.

Comment: Para hacerlas responsiva en el css te tienes que dirigir al link , a la etiqueta <a> la cual tiene propiedades para cuando el raton esta encima del link , si ha sido clickado, etc . Dale un tamaño al contenedor que esta dentro del link , y en la propiedad de la etiqueta <a> le cambias el tamaño :
aqui tienes documentacion https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp dende estan las propiedades de la etiqueta de link , la cual tomara diferentes valores segun el raton este encima , clickando , etc

Comment: En lugar de utilizar px para las medidas de la imagen utiliza porcentajes, de esta forma logras escalar la imagen para cualquier tipo de pantalla que la visualice.

Answer (score 1):

En `.img_circular` tienes un `width` con el valor `auto`, cambia el auto por `100%`

```
.img_circular{
   ...
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: donde lo debo poner?

Comment: Por favor, indica al usuario dónde tiene que añadir el código proporcionado, desarrolla un poco más tu respuesta.

Comment: Ahi ya lo modifique..

Answer (score 1):

Tu imagen no cambia de tamaño, porque tu pones un tamaño fijo en `.image-cropper`

Pero necesitas ese tamaño fijo, para asegurar que la imagen es cuadrada, antes de hacerla circular. Si no lo haces, la imagen en lugar de ser un circulo, será ovalada (de acuerdo a la proporción de la imagen original).

Lo que se me ocurre, es que hagas la imagen cuadrada usando otras unidades, como `vh`:

```
.image-cropper {
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Puedes aprender más de estas unidades en [Unidades VH y VW de CSS3](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/unidades-vh-vw-css/)

Comment: he implementado tu respuesta pero sigue del mismo tamaño

Answer (score 1):

Hice algunos cambios en tu código. Mi propuesta es utilizar la imagen como imagen de fondo `background-image`. De esta manera puedes aplicar `background-size:cover;`para que la imagen cubra todo el elemento, y si la quieres centrada puedes utilizar `background-position: center;`. Para estirar la caja utilizo un pseudo elemento `::after` donde el `padding-bottom: 100%;`

```css
.image-cropper {
  display:block;
  width: 50%;
  /*max-width:309px;*/
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image:url("https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0d/12/d7/3b/img-20160923-wa0089-largejpg.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center; 

  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.image-cropper::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <a class="image-cropper" href="#"></a>
```

Espero que sea lo que necesitas.

Answer (score -2):

Como estas? Yo usaría un `max-width=100%` y las unidades en `rem` o `em`. A mi me han funcionado... sino, con bootstrap4 que vas a renegar mucho menos. Espero te haya ayudado!